Resetting react state with css animations
I have made a path finding visualizer:
link to the github.io page
Where I store the positions of the walls and the nodes in the shortest path in an array, then check whether or not the current node's position is in those array, and then set the class of the given node based on a setTimeout.
    const wallIndex = gridInfo.walls.indexOf(nodeInfo.pos);
          if (wallIndex >= 0)
             gridInfo.shouldAnimateWalls
             ? setTimeout(() => {
                 nodeRef.current.classList.add("wall");
                 if (wallIndex >= gridInfo.walls.length - 1) {
                    setters.setShouldAnimateWalls(false);
                 }
               }, 20 * wallIndex)
             : nodeRef.current.classList.add("wall");
         else {
            nodeRef.current.classList.remove("wall");
     };

The shouldAnimateWalls boolean is to differentiate when a user is adding walls (when I don't want the walls to be animated) and when the programme is generating a maze.
The code for checking and setting whether the current node has been visited or is in the shortest path is essentially the same:
      const visitedIndex = algorithmInfo.visitedNodes
      .map((nodeString) => nodeString.split(",")
      .slice(0, 2).join(", ")).indexOf(nodeInfo.pos);

      const shortestPathIndex = algorithmInfo.shortestPath.indexOf(
        nodeInfo.pos
      );
    
      if (visitedIndex >= 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (
            (gridInfo.startPos !== nodeInfo.pos) &
            (gridInfo.endPos !== nodeInfo.pos)
          ) {
            nodeRef.current.classList.add("visited");
          }
        }, 10 * visitedIndex);
      } else {
        nodeRef.current.classList.remove("visited");
      }
      if (shortestPathIndex >= 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (
            (gridInfo.startPos !== nodeInfo.pos) &
            (gridInfo.endPos !== nodeInfo.pos)
          ) {
            nodeRef.current.classList.add("shortestPath");
          }
        }, 50 * shortestPathIndex + 10 * algorithmInfo.visitedNodes.length - 1);
      } else {
        nodeRef.current.classList.remove("shortestPath");
    };


Now, I also have a button in the header to reset the entire state of the grid. Currently I'm doing it as follows:
    const resetGrid = () => {
         setShouldAnimateWalls(false);
          setVisitedNodes(() => []);
          setShortestPath(() => []);
          setStartPos(() => pointToString(getRandomPoint(width, height)));
          setEndPos(() => pointToString(getRandomPoint(width, height)));
          setWalls(() => []);
     };

The start and end nodes are currently reset, but when I click on the window, the animations for the walls and the nodes just replays. I have to click on the window multiple times and each time just a part of the animation plays. After clicking on the window multiple times, the animations finally stop playing. But I also cannot add another maze.
How should I properly reset the entire maze?
If I reset the maze, the react state does get reset, but the animations themselves do not. Do I need to reload the entire window?
